# How to find multiple indices of minimum values in a 1D array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

For the given matrix/array:

```
A = [ 1 4 16 7 8 9 1 12 7]
```

There are two minimum numbers, and I want to be able to produce an output of locations of these numbers.

I've tried `[value, index] = min(A)`, but it only shows one position. Please help.

Comment: `ind = find(A==min(A))`. Or just `ind = (A==min(A))` to get logical indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ind = find(A==min(A));
```

to get  [linear integer indices](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/);

```
[row, col] = find(A==min(A))
```

to get [row and column integer indices](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html); or

```
ind = A==min(A);
```

to get [logical indices](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/).

Comment: this should work. A slight improvement is like [row,col]=find(A==min(A));

Comment: @16per9 Good idea; added